# Select same col with different date interval

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to select same col from database by different date interval and col value.

I've tried it by this code but I have no idea how select same col with different date interval.

```sql
SELECT
    table1.SellerAccount,
    table1.ASIN AS ASIN,
    SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) as sevenDaysBack, /* <- 7 days back */
    SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) AS twoWeeksBack, /* <- 13 days back */
    SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) as oneMonthBack, /* <- 30 days back */
    CURDATE() AS datum
FROM 
    table1
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 ON (table2.ASIN = table1.ASIN)
GROUP BY 
    table1.SellerAccount, table1.ASIN
```

Also tried by subquery, but there is problem with grouping data. I get this error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

```sql
SELECT
    table1.SellerAccount,
    @ASIN := table1.ASIN AS ASIN,
    (SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) FROM table2 
     WHERE table2.DATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND table2.ASIN = @ASIN 
     GROUP BY SellerAccountId) AS BuyBoxWeekBack,
    (SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) FROM table2 
     WHERE table2.DATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND table2.ASIN = @ASIN 
     GROUP BY SellerAccountId) AS BuyBoxTwoWeekBack,
    (SELECT AVG(table2.BuyBox) FROM table2 
     WHERE table2.DATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 300 DAY AND table2.ASIN = @ASIN 
     GROUP BY SellerAccountId) AS BuyBoxMonthBack,
    CURDATE() AS date
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY 
    table1.SellerAccount, table1.ASIN
```

I expect the output should return grouped data by SellerAccount and ASIN. And AVG buybox col by ASIN and Date interval.